# Share Message in google+ with call back using javascript

Tags: javascript, google-plus

I want to share message in google+ and need response if the message is **shared successfully or not**.

```
<div class="g-plus" data-onendinteraction="share_endinteraction">share</div>

function share_endinteraction(jsonParam) {

alert("Data" + jsonParam.type);

}
```

also tried using this function also

```
 $('.g-plus').click(function() {

            $('.g-plus').attr("data-href", "http://www.google.com"); gapi.plus.go();
            window.open('https://plusone.google.com/_/+1/confirm?hl=en&url='+encodeURIComponent('www.google.com')+'&title='+encodeURIComponent('check it out'),'', 'menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,height=600,width=600');
    return true;
        share_endinteraction();
        });
```

we are unable to get callback response.

If any one can help me out to get callback response succesfull in any of social media.

Please anyone can help